# RESTEasy and JNDI datasource from JBoss

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jndi, resteasy

I am trying to use a datasource declared in my JBoss EAP 7 `standalone.xml`:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/my_db" pool-name="my_db" ...>
...
</datasource>
```

By the way I haven't found any doc about the name conventions, would `java:/datasources/my_db` be correct too?

Then as soon as I add the following to my RESTEasy web.xml (no other modifications):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>java:jboss/datasources/my_db</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the application breaks with the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003130: Class is not a root resource.
It, or one of its interfaces must be annotated with @Path:
org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource implements:
javax.sql.DataSource java.io.Serializable
```

How to access JNDI datasources in RESTEasy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running in a WildFly/JBossEAP 7 container you can completely forget that it's implementation of JAX-RS is built on RestEASY.

You can completely remove the web.xml (or at least any RestEASY config that it contains) and just build "pure" JAX-RS:

```
@Path("...")
public class SomeRestService {

    @Resource(name="java:jboss/datasources/my_db")
    private DataSource ds;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyPojo someResource() {

        try(Connection con = ds.getConnection()) {
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

You can inject EJBs, CDI beans, PersistenceContexts, etc. It will "just work".

Comment: Indeed I figured this out yesterday after posting my question and updating my code to use Application instead of web.xml ;-) There is another option I'll post in an answer.

Comment: Actually you need `lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/my_db"` in the resource annotation otherwise it won't return the correct datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer is correct but there is another way to do it:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/datasources/my_db");
```

I prefer using `@Resource`